# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'activeLayer'

Tags: python, pyqgis, ubuntu

I am running a PyQGIS script in Ubuntu to read a CSV file that includes the latitude and longitude of several points. My QGIS version is 2.18.17. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()

# Put your pyqgis code here:
uri = "file:////home/aka000/site4/PyQGIS/Tailings_Pond_1A.csv?encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Lat", "Long","epsg:4326")

#Make a vector layer
eq_layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri,"eq-data","delimitedtext")

#Check if layer is valid
if not eq_layer.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")

#Add CSV data    
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(eq_layer)

points = [QgsPointXY(f['long'], f['lat']) for f in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]
```

I get this error related to the last line of the script:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'activeLayer'
```

To clarify how I run the script:
1- I create the test.py script in my account on the Linux machine.
2- I run it from the Command Line (Terminal): ./test.py

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/426312/edit) to specify exactly how you are running your script.

Comment: @user2856 I edited my question. Please let me know if it's not still clear.